# Is this architecture still valid under Angular 1.2 and above

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, resources

There are many code examples using $resource out there. I came across this one, and the code is quite clearly laid out: https://github.com/apotry/stockwatch

I like this example because:

- It interacts with a Rails backend, which is how I am using Angular
- It uses $resource
- It is using a non-rest route (ohlc)
- The code is quite clean

To call the functions defined is quite simple as shown in the controller code below, but is it a good idea to embed the save in the factory?

**My question is**: now that Angular 1.2+ includes promises, is this type of code still valid and considered a good practice? How would this code respond to an error state?

*Here the resources are defined*

```
app.factory('Stock', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  function Stock() {
    this.service = $resource('/api/stocks/:stockId', {stockId: '@id'}, {'update': { method: 'PUT' }});
  };
  Stock.prototype.all = function() {
    return this.service.query();
  };
  Stock.prototype.delete = function(stId) {
    return this.service.remove({stockId: stId});
  };
  Stock.prototype.create = function(attr) {
    return this.service.save(attr);
  };
  Stock.prototype.update = function(attr) {
    return this.service.update(attr);
  };
  Stock.prototype.ohlc = function(stId) {
    return $resource('/api/stocks/:stockId/ohlc', {stockId: '@id'}).get({stockId: stId});
  }
  return new Stock; 
}]);
```

*Here is an example of the delete, create and a custom route (ohlc):*

```
  $scope.requestOHLC = function (stockid) {
    return Stock.ohlc(stockid);
  }

  $scope.createStock = function() {
    $scope.fetchYahooFinanceData($filter('uppercase')    ($scope.newCompany["symbol"])).then(function(result) {
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.stocks.push(Stock.create(result));
      $scope.newCompany = '';
    }, function(error) {
      $scope.error = true;
    });
  };

  $scope.deleteStock = function(id, idx) {
    Stock.delete(id);
    $scope.stocks.splice(idx, 1);
  };
```

**EDIT**

I am trying to work out a simple and clear practice for using $resource based rest routes in angular.

Different from the above code, but based on it. Assume the code below uses a service which is basically the same as the factory above. In this example I call one REST resource to create a new resource (rails table entry), and then pass the newly created id to another call. Note that **createPanelHeader** references the **$scope.selector.paneldata.primer3_parameter_id** scope variable. Not sure if this is a good practice either.

I found this would not work unless I uses **$promise.then** but this seemed a bit convoluted. Am I on the right track?

```
// Section: Create Panel header
createPrimer3Parameter = function() {
    primer3_parameter = Primer3Parameter.create().$promise.then(function(primer3_parameter){
    $scope.selector.paneldata.primer3_parameter_id = primer3_parameter.id;
    createPanelHeader();
    }, function() {
      alert('Error creating primer3parameter');
    })
};
```

**COMMENT**

I am really just trying to work out a simple method for accessing REST resources from a Rails API, with at most 1 level of nesting. I think I am missing something as it seems remarkably difficult.

What I am hearing so far is not to use $resource, even under 1.2. That I should instead use raw $http or Restangular.

Also, there seem to be some 1.2 changes that affect Restangular. The solution feels a bit like a hack to me:

https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#using-values-directly-in-templates

**UPDATE**

I didn't really come away 100% clear, so I have posted a Bounty: https://bountify.co/write-an-angular-service-for-these-rails-routes-using-restangular

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **is this type of code still valid and considered a good practice?**

This code is valid, but [considered deprecated as of 1.2.0-rc3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc3-ferocious-twitch-2013-10-14). It will work in all version of angular 1.2 and 1.3 up to [but not including **1.3.0-beta10**, where automatic promise unwrapping has been removed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#130-beta10-excessive-clarification-2014-05-23).

```
$scope.stocks.push(Stock.create(result));
```

In the line above you've created an array of *promise* objects on `$scope`. Then [in index.html.erb](https://github.com/apotry/stockwatch/blob/master/app/views/watchlist/index.html.erb) you are referencing the promise directly via the `stock` iterator:

```
<li ng-repeat="stock in stocks">
      <div id='symbol'>
        {{stock.symbol}}
      </div>
```

The non-deprecated way of handling promises does not allow you to bind directly to the promise  like this.

> **How would this code respond to an error state?**

The app is handling errors here:

```
}, function(error) {
  $scope.error = true;
});
```

and here:

```
<div ng-show="error">
    There was a problem with the Yahoo Finance API. Please try again later.
</div>
```

For error handling, you're not binding with a promise directly so this works fine in all versions of angular.

### A better way?

First, shelf the javascript directory structure in the **stockwatch** example. Then, [**follow this directory structure**](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) instead. Finally, integrate [**Restangular**](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) into your project. Create a `stockModel` factory that internally instantiates a `Restangular` object, but returns the object that will be populated later after the promise resolves (`model`). Instead of binding a promise in your partial, bind the unpopulated result object.

```
.factory('stocksModel', function (Restangular) {
  var model = {};
  var rest_stocks = Restangular.all('stocks');

  model.doSomethingRESTful = function (...) {
    // return a promise in case the controller needs it
    return rest_carts.some_restangular_method(...)
      .then(function() {
        model.some_data_which_was_acquired_RESTfully = ...;
      });
  };

  return model;
});
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.stocks = stocksModel;
```

In your partial:

```
{{stocks.some_data_which_was_acquired_RESTfully}}
```

Comment: Why not mention how to unwrap the promise "manually". It shouldn;t be difficult...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give an example of a good practice under 1.2? Please also see my additional code under edit

Comment: Thank you. In fact I had looked at Restangular... but wanted to stick with standard angular... is $resource so difficult to use that I should go for Restangular instead?

Comment: Just as ui-router is far superior to ngRouter, Restangular is much better than $resource. It yields cleaner, more concise code and it is based on standard angular constructs just as `$resource` is. If you're set on using `$resource` then maybe someone else can help because I haven't touched it in some while, just as I never use ngRouter anymore.

Answer (score 2):

### To be blunt

No. If possible, I would improve the code so that is it more maintainable and update to date with  Angular. Let me explain why it is a good idea. . .

### Why are you making your life so hard?

Angular is a wonderful framework that lets you tackle fairly complex problems with simple solutions. The dark side of Angular is it is easy to over engineer a solution if you go off the beaten path. Angular exposes a lot of the internals so it is tempting (and fun!) to muck around with it instead of going for the simple route.

#### Growing pains

I believe what you are dealing with is due to the growing pains Angular has had as it matured as project. A lot of side projects sprung up to fix the leaky holes that have since been plugged.

### Rails and Angular, fast friends

So I am basing this off of how I have grown to use Rails with Angular. The examples are pulled from a [pet project that is not going anywhere](https://github.com/mguymon/mmd/tree/a_new_lease/app/assets/javascripts). Unfortunately, this is all in coffeescript, so hopefully that wont cause you problems. It is structured how I found works best with Rails, while keeping the spirit and fun of Angular.

```
* app/assets/javascripts
   * app
       * project_name_app.js.coffee.erb 
       * controllers
           * controllers.js 
       * directives 
           * directives.js
       * filters    
           * filters.js
       * resources  
           * resources.js
       * services
           * services.js
```

Rails' asset pipeline wraps everything up using the `application.js` with the include:

```
//= require app/project_name_app
```

In the [app/project_name_app.js.coffee.erb](https://github.com/mguymon/mmd/blob/a_new_lease/app/assets/javascripts/app/deployer_app.js.coffee.erb), it loads all of the directories with the includes

```
#= require_self
#= require app/controllers/controllers
#= require app/directives/directives
#= require app/filters/filters
#= require app/resources/resources
#= require app/services/services
```

Last, each of the sub directories js (controllers.js, directives.js, filters.js, resources.js, services.js) simply loads everything in that directory:

```
//= require_tree .
```

With this setup, the `project_name_app.js.coffee.erb` is loaded first, setting up Angular, the dependencies, and the app configuration. Then the controller, directives, filters, etc are loaded. One of the perks is new javascript added to a sub directory is automatically included thanks to the `require_tree`.

### Keeping the $resource simple

The best $resources are RESTFUL. Meaning that it is the sample URL and the functionality changes based on the http method of the request. The downside is, if you have different URLs, you will probably need multiple resources. An example from the [users_resource.js.coffee](https://github.com/mguymon/mmd/blob/a_new_lease/app/assets/javascripts/app/resources/users.js.coffee.erb):

```
angular.module("DeployerApp.resources").factory "Users", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/users.json", {},
    index:
      method: "GET"
      isArray: true
      type: "User"


angular.module("DeployerApp.resources").factory "User", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/users/:user_id.json", {},
    show:
      method: "GET"
    update:
      method: "PUT"

angular.module("DeployerApp.resources").factory "CurrentUser", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/users/current.json", {},
    show:
      method: "GET"
```

To get all users, you call `Users.index()`. To get a single user, you call `User.show( user_id: 1 )`. Last, a convenience $resource I that often use, to get the current authenticated user, `CurrentUser.show()`.

Pretty straight forward and easy to read, avoiding have to have *thick* models. Each of the User $resources can be tested separately.

### Angular is ready to do the work

You really only need to start mucking with `$promise` if you have some complicated juggling act when dealing with multiple responses. I have found it is simpler to just pass in the success and error callbacks to the $resource, for example:

```
CurrentUser.show success = (user) ->
    $scope.currentUser = user
, error = (data,status) ->
    # redirect to login
```

The variable names help make the code more readable, without them the coffeescript function definitions kind of blend together.

### Simpler is always better

You do not need to worry about the `$promise.then` of the $resource, allowing you to tidying things up.

Comment: wait! you mean if I use $http, I don't need to worry about promises?

Comment: There are always promises being used. The $http, which $resource is built on, provides some short cuts for brevity.